# How to assign an NSG to this subnet

Tags: azure, terraform

The following code successfully deploys an NSG with inbound and outbound rules, but I'm not sure how to extend this further so that the NSG attaches to the subnet specified.

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**main.tf**

```
module "subnet" {
  source              = "../../../modules/terraform-azure-module-network/virtual-network/subnet"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  vnet_name           = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  subnets             = var.subnets
}

module "network_security_group" {
  source              = "../../../modules/terraform-azure-module-network/nsg"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  name                = "t-ause-lp-dev-sandbox-app-nsg"
  inbound_rules = [
    {
      name                       = "AZ_Allow_Inbound_Example1"
      priority                   = 100
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "*"
      direction                  = "Inbound"
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "*"
      source_address_prefix      = "VirtualNetwork"
      destination_address_prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
    },
    {
      name                       = "AZ_Allow_Inbound_Example2"
      priority                   = 101
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "*"
      direction                  = "Inbound"
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "*"
      source_address_prefix      = "VirtualNetwork"
      destination_address_prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
    }
  ]
  outbound_rules = [
    {
      name                       = "AZ_Allow_Outbound_Example1"
      priority                   = 100
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "*"
      direction                  = "Outbound"
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "*"
      source_address_prefix      = "VirtualNetwork"
      destination_address_prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
    },
    {

      name                       = "AZ_Allow_Outbound_Example2"
      priority                   = 101
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "*"
      direction                  = "Outbound"
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "*"
      source_address_prefix      = "VirtualNetwork"
      destination_address_prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
    }

  ]
}
```

**outputs.tf**

```
output "root_subnet_names" {
  value = module.subnet.subnet_names
}


output "root_subnet_address_prefixes" {
  value = module.subnet.subnet_address_prefixes
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "resource_group_names" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["Benedict", "Santosh", "Johan", "Jude"]
}

variable "subnets" {
  type = map(object({
    name           = string
    address_prefix = string
  }))
  default = {
    subnet1 = { name = "App", address_prefix = "10.101.80.0/24" }
    subnet2 = { name = "DB", address_prefix = "10.101.81.0/24" }
    # nsg_id          = string
  }
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "t-ause-lp-dev-sandbox-network-rg"
}

variable "location" {
  type        = string
  description = "location of resource group"
  default     = "australiasoutheast"
}

variable "nsg_name" {
  description = "The name of the network security group"
  type        = string
  default = "t-ause-lp-dev-sandbox-dev-app-nsg"
}
```

**module-subnet-main.tf**

```
 # Create the Subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each = var.subnets

  name                 = each.value.name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = var.vnet_name
  address_prefixes     = [each.value.address_prefix]
}
```

**module-subnet-outputs.tf**

```
    output "subnet_names" {
  value = { for subnet_key, subnet_value in azurerm_subnet.subnet : subnet_key => subnet_value.name }
}

output "subnet_ids" {
  value = { for subnet_key, subnet_value in azurerm_subnet.subnet : subnet_key => subnet_value.id }
}

output "subnet_address_prefixes" {
  value = { for subnet_key, subnet_value in azurerm_subnet.subnet : subnet_key => subnet_value.address_prefixes }
}
```

**module-subnet-variables.tf**

```
# Subnet Variables

    variable "resource_group_name" {
      type = string
    }
    
    variable "vnet_name" {
      type = string
    }
    
    variable "subnets" {
      type = map(object({
        name           = string
        address_prefix = string
      }))
    }
```

**module-nsg-main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = var.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  tags                = var.tags

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = var.inbound_rules
    content {
      name                                       = security_rule.value.name
      priority                                   = security_rule.value.priority
      access                                     = security_rule.value.access
      protocol                                   = security_rule.value.protocol
      direction                                  = "Inbound"
      source_address_prefix                      = security_rule.value.source_address_prefix
      source_address_prefixes                    = security_rule.value.source_address_prefixes
      source_application_security_group_ids      = security_rule.value.source_application_security_group_ids
      source_port_range                          = security_rule.value.source_port_range
      source_port_ranges                         = security_rule.value.source_port_ranges
      destination_address_prefix                 = security_rule.value.destination_address_prefix
      destination_address_prefixes               = security_rule.value.destination_address_prefixes
      destination_application_security_group_ids = security_rule.value.destination_application_security_group_ids
      destination_port_range                     = security_rule.value.destination_port_range
      destination_port_ranges                    = security_rule.value.destination_port_ranges
      description                                = security_rule.value.description
    }
  }

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = var.outbound_rules
    content {
      name                                       = security_rule.value.name
      priority                                   = security_rule.value.priority
      access                                     = security_rule.value.access
      protocol                                   = security_rule.value.protocol
      direction                                  = "Outbound"
      source_address_prefix                      = security_rule.value.source_address_prefix
      source_address_prefixes                    = security_rule.value.source_address_prefixes
      source_application_security_group_ids      = security_rule.value.source_application_security_group_ids
      source_port_range                          = security_rule.value.source_port_range
      source_port_ranges                         = security_rule.value.source_port_ranges
      destination_address_prefix                 = security_rule.value.destination_address_prefix
      destination_address_prefixes               = security_rule.value.destination_address_prefixes
      destination_application_security_group_ids = security_rule.value.destination_application_security_group_ids
      destination_port_range                     = security_rule.value.destination_port_range
      destination_port_ranges                    = security_rule.value.destination_port_ranges
      description                                = security_rule.value.description

    }
  }
}
```

**module-nsg-outputs.tf**

```
    output "id" {
  value       = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id
  description = "The network security group configuration ID."
}

output "name" {
  value       = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.name
  description = "The name of the network security group."
}

output "resource_group_name" {
  value       = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.resource_group_name
  description = "The name of the resource group in which to create the network security group."
}

output "location" {
  value       = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.location
  description = "The location/region where the network security group is created."
}

output "tags" {
  value       = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.tags
  description = "The tags assigned to the resource."
}
```

**module-nsg-variables.tf**

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "location" {
  type        = string
  description = "location of resource group"
}

variable "name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the network security group."
}

variable "tags" {
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
  description = "A mapping of tags to assign to the resource."
}

variable "inbound_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    name                                       = string
    priority                                   = number
    access                                     = string
    protocol                                   = string
    direction                                  = string
    source_address_prefix                      = optional(string)
    source_address_prefixes                    = optional(list(string))
    source_application_security_group_ids      = optional(list(string))
    source_port_range                          = optional(string)
    source_port_ranges                         = optional(list(string))
    destination_address_prefix                 = optional(string)
    destination_address_prefixes               = optional(list(string))
    destination_application_security_group_ids = optional(list(string))
    destination_port_range                     = optional(string)
    destination_port_ranges                    = optional(list(string))
    description                                = optional(string)
  }))
  default     = []
  description = "List of objects that represent the configuration of each inbound rule."
}

variable "outbound_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    name                                       = string
    priority                                   = number
    access                                     = string
    protocol                                   = string
    source_address_prefix                      = optional(string)
    source_address_prefixes                    = optional(list(string))
    source_application_security_group_ids      = optional(list(string))
    source_port_range                          = optional(string)
    source_port_ranges                         = optional(list(string))
    destination_address_prefix                 = optional(string)
    destination_address_prefixes               = optional(list(string))
    destination_application_security_group_ids = optional(list(string))
    destination_port_range                     = optional(string)
    destination_port_ranges                    = optional(list(string))
    description                                = optional(string)
  }))
  default     = []
  description = "List of objects that represent the configuration of each outbound rule."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tired to attach a specified subnet to NSG using terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successully

You need to connect the NSG and the subnet in your Terraform configuration. Your code snippets show that you have created both NSGs and subnets, but you have not linked them together.

You cannot use the `network_security_group_id` attribute inside the `azurerm_subnet` resource. To link a network security group (NSG) with a subnet, you have to use a different resource named `azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association`.

**My file structure:**

```
your-terraform-project/
│
├── main.tf
├── variables.tf
├── terraform.tfvars
└── modules/
    ├── subnet/
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   └── variables.tf
    └── nsg/
        ├── main.tf
        └── variables.tf
```

**My terraform configuration:**

**main.tf:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

module "network_security_group" {
  source              = "./modules/nsg"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  name                = var.nsg_name
  inbound_rules       = [
    {
      name                       = "AllowSSH"
      priority                   = 100
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "Tcp"
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "22"
      source_address_prefix      = "*"
      destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }
    # Add more rules as needed
  ]
  outbound_rules      = [
    {
      name                       = "AllowAllOutbound"
      priority                   = 100
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "Tcp"
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "*"
      source_address_prefix      = "*"
      destination_address_prefix = "Internet"
    }
  ]
}

module "subnet" {
  source              = "./modules/subnet"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  vnet_name           = var.vnet_name
  subnets             = var.subnets
  nsg_id              = module.network_security_group.id
}


output "subnet_ids" {
  value = module.subnet.subnet_ids
}

output "nsg_id" {
  value = module.network_security_group.id
}
```

**variable.tf:**

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group"
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The Azure region to deploy the resources"
  type        = string
}

variable "vnet_name" {
  description = "The name of the virtual network"
  type        = string
}

variable "subnets" {
  description = "A map of subnet configurations"
  type = map(object({
    name           = string
    address_prefix = string
  }))
}

variable "nsg_name" {
  description = "The name of the network security group"
  type        = string
}

# Add additional variables as needed
```

**terraform.tfvars:**

```
resource_group_name = "demorg-vk"
location            = "East US"
vnet_name           = "demovk-vnet"
nsg_name            = "demovk-nsg"

subnets = {
  subnet1 = {
    name           = "vksubnet1"
    address_prefix = "10.0.1.0/24"
  }
}
```

##### `modules/subnet/main.tf`

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each             = var.subnets
  name                 = each.value.name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = var.vnet_name
  address_prefixes     = [each.value.address_prefix]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "subnet_nsg_association" {
  for_each = var.subnets

  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.key].id
  network_security_group_id = var.nsg_id
}

output "subnet_ids" {
  value = { for k, v in azurerm_subnet.subnet : k => v.id }
}
```

##### `modules/subnet/variable.tf`

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group"
  type        = string
}

variable "vnet_name" {
  description = "The name of the virtual network"
  type        = string
}

variable "subnets" {
  description = "A map of subnet configurations"
  type = map(object({
    name           = string
    address_prefix = string
  }))
}

variable "nsg_id" {
  description = "The ID of the Network Security Group"
  type        = string
}
```

##### `modules/nsg/main.tf`

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = var.inbound_rules
    content {
      name                       = security_rule.value.name
      priority                   = security_rule.value.priority
      direction                  = "Inbound"
      access                     = security_rule.value.access
      protocol                   = security_rule.value.protocol
      source_port_range          = security_rule.value.source_port_range
      destination_port_range     = security_rule.value.destination_port_range
      source_address_prefix      = security_rule.value.source_address_prefix
      destination_address_prefix = security_rule.value.destination_address_prefix
    }
  }

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = var.outbound_rules
    content {
      name                       = security_rule.value.name
      priority                   = security_rule.value.priority
      direction                  = "Outbound"
      access                     = security_rule.value.access
      protocol                   = security_rule.value.protocol
      source_port_range          = security_rule.value.source_port_range
      destination_port_range     = security_rule.value.destination_port_range
      source_address_prefix      = security_rule.value.source_address_prefix
      destination_address_prefix = security_rule.value.destination_address_prefix
    }
  }
}


output "id" {
  value = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id
}
```

##### `modules/nsg/variable.tf`

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group"
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The Azure region to deploy the NSG"
  type        = string
}

variable "name" {
  description = "The name of the network security group"
  type        = string
}

variable "inbound_rules" {
  description = "List of inbound security rules"
  type = list(object({
    name                       = string
    priority                   = number
    access                     = string
    protocol                   = string
    source_port_range          = string
    destination_port_range     = string
    source_address_prefix      = string
    destination_address_prefix = string
  }))
  default = []
}

variable "outbound_rules" {
  description = "List of outbound security rules"
  type = list(object({
    name                       = string
    priority                   = number
    access                     = string
    protocol                   = string
    source_port_range          = string
    destination_port_range     = string
    source_address_prefix      = string
    destination_address_prefix = string
  }))
  default = []
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]